# Accept url as parameter in MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I would like to accept url as parameter for one of the action. But, I'm getting "**HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.**" error for the below example. How do I resolve this issue?

**Example:**

```
http://localhost:8343/http://google.com
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{hostUrl}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", hostUrl = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed by following these steps.**

- Change Web project properties to "Use IIS Local Server" and check "Use IIS Express"
- Add the following setting in Web.config inside :

```xml
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL encoding for the parameter `http://google.com`.

So, navigate here:

```
http://localhost:8343/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

(I just used an online [URL encoder tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).)

Answer (score 1):

Use

[`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

or

[`Server.URLEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Depending where you are doing the encoding.